# Require and memory: use in global or function scope

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm a relative beginner with Javascript and am refactoring some code which uses `require`. I'm wondering if there is any memory advantage to only "requiring" an external library within function scope if it is only to be used a few times in the runtime lifespan.

For example: In my existing code I use `fast-csv` but I only use it in one function which will only be called rarely.

What I have now:

```
const csv = require("fast-csv");

function importCSV(filepath) {
       csv.fromPath(filepath, { headers: true, ignoreEmpty: true })
           .on("data", function (data) {
                // do some stuff
            })
            .on("end", function () {
                 // finish up
            });
}
```

---

Is this any better in terms of memory usage?

```
function importCSV(filepath) {
   var csv = require("fast-csv");
       csv.fromPath(filepath, { headers: true, ignoreEmpty: true })
           .on("data", function (data) {
                // do some stuff
            })
            .on("end", function () {
                 // finish up
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, I believe there is very little or no difference in memory usage here because `require` caches modules in memory. For example, the first time you call `require('fast-csv')`, it reads files off of the disk. Subsequent calls to `require('fast-csv')` use the cached object in [`require.cache`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_cache).

You could delete the module from the cache, but that will slow down future require calls. It seems like a premature optimization to worry about the size of modules in memory.